# If get var two values

Tags: if-statement, variables, get, var

Cannot figure out how put two values in this line of code!

```
if($_GET['var']=='cast')
```

Want use **cast** and **distributedstudio**

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: `if($_GET['var']=='cast' && $_GET['var']=='distributedstudio')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a comment on the question above, your attempt was:

```
if($_GET['var']=='cast' && $_GET['var']=='distributedstudio')
```

Consider the logic you're trying to express here.  The value in `$_GET['var']` *can never* simultaneously be both `'cast'` **and** `'distributedstudio'`.

Did you mean to use the "or" operator?:

```
if($_GET['var']=='cast' || $_GET['var']=='distributedstudio')
```

Or perhaps query different `$_GET` values?:

```
if($_GET['var1']=='cast' && $_GET['var2']=='distributedstudio')
```

Overall, to answer the question being asked, you already know how to "put two values" in your condition.  The code you've written is syntactically correct and will execute as designed.

The problem is that the logic of your condition can never be `true`.  Whatever logic you're trying to express, break apart that logic into semantic components and write your code from there.  For example, the semantics might be: "if var equals 'cast' or var equals 'distributedstudio'".  Whatever your intended logic is, that's up to you.

Comment: Thank you @David `if($_GET['var']=='cast' || $_GET['var']=='distributedstudio')` works perfectly